# Confusion between probability distribution and probability density functions for the sum of two RV

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

I am a bit confused about the following statements:

1. The probability distribution of the sum of two or more "independent" random variables is the convolution of their individual distributions.
2. The probability mass function or probability density function of a sum of random variables is the convolution of their corresponding probability mass functions or probability density functions respectively.

Does this mean that for the second statement, statistical independence is not required anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Independence is very essential in the discrete case also. The second statement is wrong.

Counterexample: let $X$ take values $0$ and $1$ with probability $\frac 1 2$ each and $Y=-X$. Then $P(X+Y=1)=0$ but the convolution assigns possitive probability for this.

Comment: I quoted this paragraph from Wikipedia. So you're saying that for the general case of the sum of two RV, we can't say anything about the pdf?

Comment: It is a very serious mistake if someone made such a statement on Wikipedia. You cannot say anything about the distribution of the sum of two random variables knowing only their individual distributions. I have added a counterexample to my answer.   @Niousha